# Wave function - Working towards Orthonormal solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, superposition

As you can see below, the two pages attached describe how to obtain the final solution of orthonormality.

I do not completely follow the discussion but I will talk you through what I DO understand and then hopefully you could fill in the gaps ?

So, we consider a wavefunction $\psi$ which when measured has discrete eigenvalues $f_n$.

When we obtain $f_n$ we then have $\psi$=$\psi_n$

We assume the eigenfunction ($\psi_n$) is normalise as per eqn. 3.1.

Applyin the principle of superposition : Since we have multiple eigenfunctions which satisfy the wavefunction $\psi$ we must also be able to state these eigenfunction as a linear combination which in turn is also a solution.

Hence, we obtain 3.2.

**First problem :** In 3.2 where did $a_n$ come from ?

This completes the first picture discussion. Now moving onto the second picture :

**Second problem :** The first paragraph talks about bilinear expressions and what not. I do not follow the discussion in this section or how 3.3 was obtained.

If these two issues are explained to me I think I can work out the rest. :)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you please edit your question to quote the relevant parts of the text, rather than posting pictures of the book?

Comment: Will keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: That's good, but please do it this time as well. (You can ask for help editing, if you don't know the necessary MathJax syntax or something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part 1: As described in the text book, $\Psi$ is a linear combination of its eigenfunctions. $a_n$ is just a scalar multiple of that state, which basically tells you how much goes into that state, its the probability amplitude of that state.

Therefore the probability to be in state $\Psi_n$ is equal to $\|a_n\|^2 = a_n a^*_n$.

Part 2: It should be clear now that the summation of all $\|a_n\|^2$ values should give you 1, i.e The probability of the system being in one of its eigenstates is exactly 1 (its surely in one of its states!).